# What kind of verb should be used after 'A century of + a plural noun'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

In the following sentence, which verb is right?

> A century of discoveries in genetics ( has / have ) unlocked the
> secrets of our DNA.

Comment: This kind of question is a common stumbling block. Hint: What noun is the subject of the verb *unlock*? Compare to this—What form of the verb *weigh* would you use in *This bag of rocks ___ a lot*?

Comment: Native speakers are split on this. Some use the singular with **century** and others would use the plural with **discoveries**.  **century** is the grammatical subject in old-school grammar. But I think many editors nowadays would let either form pass.

Comment: I agree with @TimR. But note that it can be very dependent on context. I doubt that even the most nowadays of editors would accept \**This bag of rocks weigh a lot*.

Comment: I think most editors would play it safe and swap problematic plural ***discoveries*** to ***research*** or similar. Google Books has 3-4 different instances of singular *A century of discoveries **has...,*** and no hits at all for plural *A century of discoveries **have...*** But there are shedloads of hits for [***a century of research has...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+century+of+research+has%2Ca+century+of+discoveries+has%2Ca+century+of+discoveries+have&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: ...essentially, if there's a usage where native speakers *who regularly interact with each other* have different preferences, there's usually a tendency to ***find alternative phrasing*** rather than try to find out which version your boss prefers (so he doesn't pigeonhole you as "ignorant", and therefore not worthy of a pay rise! :)

Comment: The head of the NP subject "a century of discoveries in genetics" is the singular noun "century", so the verb should be the singular "has".

Comment: If the subject were "a **lot** of discoveries" (or "a **bunch**", "a **ton**", "a **handful**", etc.) it would clearly take plural agreement in modern usage despite the technically singular head noun. I would probably say "a century of discoveries have", but "has" doesn't sound wrong to me there, so it doesn't surprise me that speakers disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Has.

The subject of the sentence is "century."  You must make it agree.

If you wanted to rephrase it, it could be

> A century's discoveries in genetics have unlocked the secrets of our DNA.

or

> Over the last century, discoveries in genetics have unlocked the secrets of our DNA.

But it would have to be rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go either way, depending on where you want the emphasis.

If you consider the subject of the sentence to be **a century of discoveries**, that's a singlular subject and you would say **has**. Here the emphasis is on the period of time during which people made new discoveries.

If you consider the subject off the sentence to be **discoveries**, that's plural and you would say **have**. Here the emphasis would be on the discoveries themselves.

Comment: The head of the subject NP can only be "century". Only with certain non-count quantificational nouns like "lot" and "plenty" does the number of the complement of "of"  determine the number of the whole NP.

Comment: @BillJ: You don't consider **century** to be analyzable as such a non-count quantificational noun?

Comment: *The Guardian* [has no problem with it](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/may/25/sons-lovers-dh-lawrence-blake-morrison): "A century of readers have reached for the same adjective." A [scientific article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1387181122006540) says: "A decade of collaborative efforts have led to remarkable innovations". [This page](https://friendshipsy.com/more-than-a-decade-of-friendship-quotes/) says "I hope that these more than a decade of friendship quotes have inspired you." So it seems many speakers are happy to use it this way.